# serialization of a List containing another List

Tags: c#, json, serialization, collections, deserialization

I guess my problem is about (de)serializing a list of class, which has a property which itself is a List, which give me some trouble. Lemme first drop some code sample and explain.

The class I serialize is a follow :

```
public class Cell : ICell
{
    #region ICell Implementation

    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Coordinates")]
    public Coordinates Coordinates { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IsHint")]
    public bool IsHint { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Points")]
    public Point[] Points { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Links")]
    public List<LinkData> Links { get; set; } 

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Cell(int id, int number, Coordinates coordinates, Point[] points, List<LinkData> links,  bool isHint = false)
    {
        Id = id;
        Number = number;
        IsHint = isHint;
        Coordinates = coordinates;
        Links = links; // always empty !!!
        Points = points;
    }


    // Code not serialized
   }
```

The serialization :

```
 public void Save(string filePath)
 {
    using (var file = File.CreateText(filePath))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        };
        serializer.Serialize(file, board.Cells);
    }
}
```

Now the deserialization :

```
cells = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cell>>(file.ReadToEnd());
```

When I open the serialized file, it looks perfect to me, here is Cell #1 :

```
{
    "ID": 0,
    "Coordinates": { "Coordinate": "0, -3" },
    "IsHint": false,
    "Number": 0,
    "Points": 
     [
        "813, 288",
         "761, 318",
         "709, 288",
         "709, 228",
         "761, 198",
         "813, 228" 
    ],
    "Links": 
    [
        {
            "CellId1": 0,
            "CellId2": 1,
            "Location": "813, 258"
          }
    ]
},
```

My problem is, when this very line get instanciated upon deserialization, everything is fine but the content of "Links" is empty. My guess is that nesting List need more sophisticated deserialization ?

Thanks for you helps !

Edit : here is how LinkData struct (had to do it to avoid overflow with resolving Cell) is like :

```
public struct LinkData
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public LinkData(int cellId1, int cellId2, Point linkLocation)
    {
        CellId1 = cellId1;
        CellId2 = cellId2;
        Location = linkLocation;
    }

    [JsonProperty("CellId1")]
    public int CellId1 { get; }

    [JsonProperty("CellId2")]
    public int CellId2 { get; }

    [JsonProperty("Location")]
    public Point Location { get; }

    public static LinkData Empty => new LinkData(0, 0, Point.Empty);
}
```

Edit #2 :

```
"Links": 
    [
        {
            "CellId1": 0,
            "CellId2": 1,
            "Location": "813, 258"
          }
    ]
```

Why is Json part of code not turing into a List, why is it null upon deserialization ?

Comment: Can you provide LinkData and Points object structure in example?

Comment: Edited my post to show LinkData. Points is just a regular System.Drawing.Point array where I stored the points to draw the cell (a regular hexagon in my case).

Comment: Is `linkLocation` the same as `location`? What happens if you change `linkLocation` to `location`?

Comment: Nope, setting both to location leads to the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show me the `LinkData` constructor _after_ you made the change I suggested? Also, please mention @myname or it won't notify me about your comment. Also, did you put a breakpoint in the constructor? Did the breakpoint get hit?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to change JsonProperty from `Location` to `linkLocation` in `LinkData` struct

```
[JsonProperty("linkLocation")]
public Point Location { get; }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I tried this change but sadly, ouput is still the same : Links is null even if the file contains one instance of it.

Comment: After making above change, I can see that object is not null. Result: https://imgur.com/SQe6yjf  
Code: https://imgur.com/lDQqzHl

Comment: Then it blows my mind that it's working for you, can you send an image or json code for the LinkData ? How comes that not only LinkData isn't instiancated for me and on the top of that I'd love to know why. Because solving without understanding is pointless if you know what I mean. But thanks for your help & testing on your side the code I pasted ! Much appreciated !

Comment: look at this file. I have not refactored the code but this s enough to look at the code: https://github.com/jayesh-tanna/coding-problem-solution/blob/master/Program.cs

Comment: This is seriallized json in file: https://github.com/jayesh-tanna/coding-problem-solution/blob/master/test.txt

Comment: I just gave a try to your deserialization method, which is almost the same than me, but cell[0].Link[0].x just crashes because of a null exception of Link object..How did you get it working ? with the json & code I pasted ?

Comment: Why: If you look at the serialized string in file, its linkLocation, so when you deserialized that json string from file, it looks for exact property name that is linkLocation. While passing it to constructor of struct, it needs same parameter name as you have given in JsonPropertyName. look at this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#deserialization-behavior

Comment: It's about 5AM here, what you posted is working as intented. I think after sleeping, with all your advices I should be good to go, thanks for your help man !

Comment: Okay, can't sleep but still something strikes me ass odd, you said that property name has to match the one in the constructor, but in your code there are[JsonProperty("CellId1")] & [JsonProperty("CellId2")] while constructor is cellId1, int cellId2.